# generating links dynamically

Tags: php, html, dynamic-links

so i guess this is pretty easy for most of you, but i can't figure this out.

im trying to make the links dynamic eg: href="linkname(#1 or #2 etc)"

any ideas?

```
 <?php if ($top_fundraisers && is_array($top_fundraisers)): ?>
        <?php foreach ($top_fundraisers as $index => $fundraiser): ?>
           <a title="" class="fancybox" href="linkname(GENERATE CODE HERE)">
        <div class="top-fundraiser">

            <div id="newo<?php print htmlentities($index + 1); ?>" class="top-fundraiser-image">
              <img src="<?php
          if($fundraiser['member_pic_medium']) {
                  print htmlentities($fundraiser['member_pic_medium']);
          } else {
            print $template_dir . '/images/portrait_placeholder.png';
          }
              ?>"/>
            </div>
    </div>
    </a>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: what does `GENERATE CODE HERE` supposed to be?

Comment: @tradyblix href="linkname(#1 or #2 etc)"

Comment: Try this one `<?php echo myLink; ?>` where `myLink` is a variable which holds the link or `<?php echo getLink() ?>` where `getLink` is a function which returns the link instead of `linkname(GENERATE CODE HERE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose below is what you need.

```
 <?php if ($top_fundraisers && is_array($top_fundraisers)): ?>
        <?php foreach ($top_fundraisers as $index => $fundraiser): ?>
           <a title="" class="fancybox" href="linkname(#<?php echo $index + 1; ?>)">
        <div class="top-fundraiser">

            <div id="newo<?php print htmlentities($index + 1); ?>" class="top-fundraiser-image">
              <img src="<?php
          if($fundraiser['member_pic_medium']) {
                  print htmlentities($fundraiser['member_pic_medium']);
          } else {
            print $template_dir . '/images/portrait_placeholder.png';
          }
              ?>"/>
            </div>
    </div>
    </a>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```